# I didn't lose all reputation for deleted posts

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

[This answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/416/what-are-the-long-term-effects-of-overfeeding-tropical-fish/417#417) I posted was deleted by [Robert Cartaino ♦](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/115/robert-cartaino) and I agree with the delete reason but the problem now is that in my [reputation changes history](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/34/precious-tijesunimi?tab=reputation) it shows **-28** for the deleted post but my change in reputation only shows **-5**. (From 581 to 576)

I didn't lose up to 28. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you hit the reputation cap for that day and of those 28 only 5 were previously added to your score.

When the answer got removed you only lost the previously gained 5 reputation instead of the full 28 reputation. (I guess it got 3 up and 1 downvote to make up the 28)

Comment: I've actually hit the reputation cap today. I guess thats the reason

Comment: That will do it. Go to [your profile] > 'reputation' > 'time'. Everything seems to be accounted for.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks. I understand now